# Class is not seeing another class, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, class, django-rest-framework

first class is using the second class object and vice versa, how do I fix this? Is there any trick for that?

Error:
NameError: name 'AktorSerializer' is not defined

```
  class FilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extrainfo = InfoSerializer(many=False)
    recenzje = RecenzjeSerializer(many=True)
    aktorzy = AktorSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = ('id', 'nazwa', 'opis', 'rok', 'rating', 'extrainfo', 'recenzje', 'aktorzy')


class AktorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filmy = FilmSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Aktor
        fields = ('imie', 'filmy')
```

Comment: You're not going to have a good time with a serializer structure like this, since they're mutually recursive. You'll get an infinitely deep output.

Comment: Its for learning purposes, I just started using drf and trying some new stuff, but thanks for advice, what should I do better here?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, having mutually recursive serializers will have DRF try to generate an infinitely deep recursive output:

```
film: Film 1
  film.aktorzy[0]: Actor 1
    film.aktorzy[0].filmy[0]: Film 1
      film.aktorzy[0].filmy[0].aktorzy[0]: Actor 1
        film.aktorzy[0].filmy[0].aktorzy[0].filmy[0]: Film 1
          ...
```

You'll probably want a different serializer for actors within films; this'll also fix your initial problem.

```
class AktorWithoutFilmsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Aktor
        fields = ("imie",)


class FilmSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    extrainfo = InfoSerializer(many=False)
    recenzje = RecenzjeSerializer(many=True)
    aktorzy = AktorWithoutFilmsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Film
        fields = (
            "id",
            "nazwa",
            "opis",
            "rok",
            "rating",
            "extrainfo",
            "recenzje",
            "aktorzy",
        )


class AktorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    filmy = FilmSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Aktor
        fields = ("imie", "filmy")
```